# React Router: this is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

У меня есть небольшой проект из трех страниц, которые прекрасно работают, но проблема в следующем: я захотел на 3 странице добавить кнопку, которая будет переадресовывать на первую. Собственно проблемный компонент:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Car from './Car/Car';

export default class Cars extends Component {
  state = {
    cars: [
      {name: 'Ford', year: 2018},
      {name: 'Audi', year: 2016},
      {name: 'Mazda', year: 2010}
    ]
  }

  goToHomePage = () => {
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/'
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{
        width: 400,
        margin: 'auto',
        paddingTop: '20px'
      }}>
        <button onClick={this.goToHomePage}>Click</button>
        <hr />
        {this.state.cars.map((car, index) => {
          return (
            <Car
              key={index}
              name={car.name}
              year={car.year}
            />
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Вот моя кнопка, которая по клику вызывает функцию goToHomePage:

```
<button onClick={this.goToHomePage}>Click</button>
```

И непосредственно функция:

```
goToHomePage = () => {
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/'
    })
}
```

Мне выдает такую ошибку:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.history.push')
```

Понимаю, что props почему-то не видно, но хотелось бы понять, почему конкретно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В классовом компоненте нужно добавить конструктор (и начальное состояние тоже в конструкторе нужно объявить):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    cars: [
      { name: "Ford", year: 2018 },
      { name: "Audi", year: 2016 },
      { name: "Mazda", year: 2010 }
    ]
  };
}
```

**Дополнение про React Router 6**

В 6 версии React Router больше нет `withRouter`, который пробрасывал в пропсы объект `history`. Поэтому для классовых компонентов придется добавить свой `hoc`:

```
function withNavigation(Component) {
  return (props) => <Component {...props} navigate={useNavigate()} />;
}
```

Компонент нужно обернуть в `withNavigation` и после этого в компоненте можно использовать функцию их пропсов `navigate`:

```
goToHomePage = () => {
  this.props.navigate("/");
};
```

В функциональных компонентах просто используется хук `useNavigate`:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const goToHomePage = () => {
  navigate("/");
};
```

Пример на codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-browser-u78e1?file=/src/Page3.jsx

Comment: К сожалению, даже добавив конструктор, ошибка осталась такой же как и была

Comment: Добавил в ответ описание про React Router 6

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { UNSAFE_NavigationContext } from "react-router-dom";
import Car from "./Car/Car";

export default class Cars extends Component {
  static contextType = UNSAFE_NavigationContext;

  state = {
    cars: [
      { name: "Ford", year: 2018 },
      { name: "Audi", year: 2016 },
      { name: "Mazda", year: 2010 },
    ],
  };

  goToHomePage = () => {
    this.context.navigator.push("/");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          width: 400,
          margin: "auto",
          paddingTop: "20px",
        }}
      >
        <button onClick={this.goToHomePage}>Click</button>
        <hr />
        {this.state.cars.map((car, index) => {
          return <Car key={index} name={car.name} year={car.year} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы: переписать функцию goToHomePage:

```
goToHomePage = () => {
    window.location.assign('/');
}
```

Насколько я понимаю, вариант из моего вопроса использовался раньше, когда роуты передавались через атрибут **component** таким образом:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/about" exact component ={Cars} />
</Routes>
```

Теперь же, насколько я понимаю, такой синтаксис устарел, а используется синтаксис с атрибутом **element**, а в таком случае this работает иначе:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" exact element={<Cars />} />
</Routes>
```

Возможно, я допустил некие неточности в объяснении, но по крайней мере, это решает проблему

Comment: теперь появилась ненужная мне перезагрузка страницы, но пока ничего поделать с этим не могу

Comment: Хотелось в целях практики реализовать переход по нажатию именно кнопки, но, к сожалению, без перезагрузки не могу это сделать. Гораздо легче просто стилизовать <NavLink> под кнопку